# -O2 optimizes printf("%s\n", str) to puts(str)

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, clang

Toying around with `clang`, I compiled a C program containing this line:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
```

When compiling without optimization, the assembly output called `printf` after setting up the registers:

```
movq    (%rcx), %rsi
movq    %rax, %rdi
movb    $0, %al
callq   _printf
```

I tried compiling with `clang -O2`. The `printf` call was replaced to a `puts` call:

```
movq    (%rsi), %rdi
callq   _puts
```

While this makes perfect sense in this case, it raises two questions:

1. How often does function call substitution happen in optimized compilation? Is this frequent or is stdio an exception?
2. Could I write compiler optimizations for my own libraries? How would I  do that?

Comment: So clang is open source, so sure you can:) wouldn't it be easier to just write more optimal code though?

Comment: I don't know (or I'd answer), but to my knowledge, it's only a few specific standard library functions that have this sort of special casing applied. `memset` is another example where compilers often special case it by identifying when it's for a fixed small size and inlining it for those cases.

Comment: That's the question. Are the libc optimizations in the clang source (I wouldn't go about forking clang) or are they in the libc source (meaning I could write optimizations in my own libraries)?

Comment: You can do whatever you like so long as you comply with the C Standard

Comment: Code like `double x = sqrt(2.0)` may get optimized to `double x = 1.4142135.....`.  Depends on compiler, depends on settings.

Comment: @M.M I think he's asking whether `clang` provides a mechanism that library authors can use to extend the optimizations, or it has to be done by modifying the compiler itself.

Comment: gcc and clang both treat a lot of functions as built-ins.  e.g. even if you don't include the any header files at all, some functions like `memset`, `memcpy`, `strlen`, etc. will still inline their builtin implementations, or be have constant-propagation happen.  (e.g. [`int foo(){return strlen("hello world!"); }` compiles to `return 12`, even without `<string.h>`](https://godbolt.org/g/dSWEHE))

Comment: Fun fact: GCC/clang will also optimize `printf("%c", foo)` to `putchar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How often does function call substitution happen in optimized compilation? Is this frequent or is stdio an exception?

The optimization that replaces `printf` with `puts` in LLVM is in the class `LibCallSimplifier`.  You can see the header file in [llvm/include/llvm/Transforms/Utils/SimplifyLibCalls.h](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/Transforms/Utils/SimplifyLibCalls.h) and the implementation in [llvm/lib/Transforms/Utils/SimplifyLibCalls.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Transforms/Utils/SimplifyLibCalls.cpp).  Looking at the files will give an example of some of the other library call replacement optimizations that are done (the header file is probably easier to start with).  And of course there are other many other optimizations that LLVM does, you can get an idea of some of them by looking at the list of [LLVM passes](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html).

> 2. Could I write compiler optimizations for my own libraries? How would I do that?

Yes you could.  LLVM is very modular and performs transformation on the IR in a series of passes.  So if you wanted to add a custom pass yourself for your own library you could do so (although it is still a fair amount of work to understand how the LLVM compiler flow works).  A good starting point is the document: [Writing an LLVM Pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html).

Answer (score 2):

This sort of optimization depends on the compiler knowing that a function named `printf` can only be the `printf` function as defined by the C standard. If program defines `printf` to mean something else then the program is invoking undefined behaviour. This lets the compiler substitute a call to `puts` in cases where it would work "as if" the standard `printf` function was being called. It doesn't have worry about it working "as if" a user defined `printf` function was called. So these kind of function substitution optimizations are pretty much limited to functions defined in the C or C++ standards. (Maybe other standards as well if the compiler somehow knows that a given standard is in force.)

Short of modifying the source code of the compiler yourself there's no way tell the compiler that these kind of function substitutions are possible with your own functions. However, with limitations, you can do something similar with inline functions.  For example you could implement something similar to the `printf`/`puts` optimization with something like this:

```
inline int myprintf(char const *fmt, char const *arg) {
    if (strcmp(fmt, "%s\n") == 0) {
         return myputs(args);
    }
    return _myprintf_impl(fmt, arg)
}
```

With optimization turned on the compiler can choose at compile time which function to call based on the `fmt` parameter, but only if it it can determine it's a constant string. If it can't, or optimization isn't enabled, then the compiler has to emit code that checks it on each call and that could easily turn this into a pessimization. Note that this optimization is dependent on the compiler knowing how `strcmp` works and removing the call entirely, and so is an example of another library function call substitution the compiler can make.

You can improve on this with GCC's `__builtin_constant_p` function:

```
inline int myprintf(char const *fmt, char const *arg) {
        if (__builtin_constant_p(fmt[0])
            && strcmp(fmt, "%s\n") == 0) {
                return myputs(arg);
        }
        return _myprintf_impl(fmt, arg);
}
```

Under GCC this results in code that never checks the format string a run time. If can determine at compile time that `fmt` is `"%s\n"` then it generates code that calls `myputs` unconditionally, otherwise it generates code that calls `_myprintf_impl` unconditionally. So with optimization enabled this function is never a pessimization. Unfortunately while clang supports the `__builtin_constant_p` function my version of clang always generates code that calls `_myprintf_impl` unconditionally.

Answer (score -4):

puts is a much smaller function than printf, executables are typically half the size. printf is only needed when converting numbers to strings for printing, you can do this using **itoa()**

Comment: This doesn't answer either question

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. The OP seems perfectly aware that it was a reasonable optimization.